# vba add text box by clicking button

Tags: ms-access, vba

In vba, I need to add textbox by clicking 'Add' button. Is it possible in VBA?
If it is, could you possible to share source code?
[Click here to see more description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euW3n.png)
In the image, after fill in first textbox, which is A, and then click 'Add button', below textbox which is marked as 'B' should appear. 
I know that this kind of thing is possible in web using jquery, but I am new to vba, so I don't know if it is possible or not. 
Any comments would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use code similar to this in your *click* event of the button:

```
Me!TextBoxB.Visible = Not IsNull(Me!TextBoxA.Value)
```